# Having issues with a javascript for loop += decimal variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

Hi guys I am building a for loop which basically generates a dynamic select options form.

Everything works fine until I try and use a decimal value as an incrementer.

for instance a normal loop would be this:

```
for(i =0; i <= 10; i++){
// do some code
}
```

The issue I am facing is that everything that is being put in is dynamic including the increment which may need to increment with decimal figures!

For instance it may need this:

```
for(i =0; i <= 10.5;i+= 1.5){
//do some code
}
```

Now the thing is that again everything is dynamic so the actual end code looks like this:

```
for(thei = 0; thei <= calchours; thei += +thetype){

}
```

Everything works 100% if the "thetype" is just 1, but as soon as its a 1.5 it only loops a few times before exiting.

Here is the Example code of what I am trying to do:

Example Html Code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="bookingtype" name="bookingtype">
    <option value="1" selected="">Hourly Bookings</option>
    <option value="1.5">1 Hour Bookings With 30 Minute Intervals</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="timefrom" name="timefrom">
    <option value="N/A" selected="">N/A</option>
    <option value="24">00:00</option>
    <option value="01">01:00</option>
    <option value="02">02:00</option>
    <option value="03">03:00</option>
    <option value="04">04:00</option>
    <option value="05">05:00</option>
    <option value="06">06:00</option>
    <option value="07">07:00</option>
    <option value="08">08:00</option>
    <option value="09" selected="selected">09:00</option>
    <option value="10">10:00</option>
    <option value="11">11:00</option>
    <option value="12">12:00</option>
    <option value="13">13:00</option>
    <option value="14">14:00</option>
    <option value="15">15:00</option>
    <option value="16">16:00</option>
    <option value="17">17:00</option>
    <option value="18">18:00</option>
    <option value="19">19:00</option>
    <option value="20">20:00</option>
    <option value="21">21:00</option>
    <option value="22">22:00</option>
    <option value="23">23:00</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="timeto" name="timeto">
    <option value="N/A" selected="">N/A</option>
    <option value="24">00:00</option>
    <option value="00.5">00:30</option>
    <option value="01">01:00</option>
    <option value="01.5">01:30</option>
    <option value="02">02:00</option>
    <option value="02.5">02:30</option>
    <option value="03">03:00</option>
    <option value="03.5">03:30</option>
    <option value="04">04:00</option>
    <option value="04.5">04:30</option>
    <option value="05">05:00</option>
    <option value="05.5">05:30</option>
    <option value="06">06:00</option>
    <option value="06.5">06:30</option>
    <option value="07">07:00</option>
    <option value="07.5">07:30</option>
    <option value="08">08:00</option>
    <option value="08.5">08:30</option>
    <option value="09">09:00</option>
    <option value="09.5">09:30</option>
    <option value="10">10:00</option>
    <option value="10.5">10:30</option>
    <option value="11">11:00</option>
    <option value="11.5">11:30</option>
    <option value="12">12:00</option>
    <option value="12.5">12:30</option>
    <option value="13">13:00</option>
    <option value="13.5">13:30</option>
    <option value="14">14:00</option>
    <option value="14.5">14:30</option>
    <option value="15">15:00</option>
    <option value="15.5">15:30</option>
    <option value="16">16:00</option>
    <option value="16.5">16:30</option>
    <option value="17" selected="selected">17:00</option>
    <option value="17.5">17:30</option>
    <option value="18">18:00</option>
    <option value="18.5">18:30</option>
    <option value="19">19:00</option>
    <option value="19.5">19:30</option>
    <option value="20">20:00</option>
    <option value="20.5">20:30</option>
    <option value="21">21:00</option>
    <option value="21.5">21:30</option>
    <option value="22">22:00</option>
    <option value="22.5">22:30</option>
    <option value="23">23:00</option>
    <option value="23.5">23:30</option>
</select>

<input id="dinnerswitch" type="checkbox" value="1">

<div id="dinnerhourdiv" class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Select Which Hour You Would Like To Have Off?</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2" id="showdinnerhours"></div>
</div>
```

Example Javascript

```
jQuery(document).read(function(){

    jQuery('#dinnerswitch').change(function(){

        if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
            jQuery(this).val(1);
        };
        if(jQuery(this).is(':checked') == false) {
            jQuery(this).val(0);
        };

        var dinnerid = jQuery('#dinnerswitch').val();

        var thestart = jQuery('#timefrom').val();
        var theend = jQuery('#timeto').val();
        var thetype = jQuery('#bookingtype').val();
        var thei = 0;
        var doi = '';

        var calchours = ((theend - thestart) / thetype);

        var calstart = '';
        var calend = '';
        var enterhours = '';
        var addingnumbers = 0;


        for(thei = 0; thei <= calchours; thei+= +thetype){

            calstart = +thestart + +thei;

            if(calstart < 12){
                calend = calstart + ' AM';
            } else {
                calend = calstart + ' PM';
            }

            calend = calend.replace('.5', ':30');

            enterhours += '<option value="' + addingnumbers + '">' + calend + '</option>';

            addingnumbers = +addingnumbers + 1;

        }

        if(dinnerid == 1){

            jQuery('#showdinnerhours').html('<select class="form-control" name="dinnerhour" id="dinnerhour">' + enterhours + '</select>');
            jQuery('#dinnerhourdiv').removeClass('hidden');

        } else {

            jQuery('#showdinnerhours').html('');
            jQuery('#dinnerhourdiv').addClass('hidden');

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: You'll need to pare this down to an [MCVE](/help/mcve). Side note: You're doing a **lot** of unnecessary conversion from string to number there. Do it up front, before the loop, rather than constantly adding unary `+`'s all over the place.

Comment: *"but as soon as its a 1.5 it only loops a few times before exiting"* how many times is "a few"? How many times did it loop exactly, what where you expecting?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek that depends on how many hours it calculates before the loop is given. If it is meant to loop 5 times it loops 3, if its meant to loop 10 times it loops 7... I see no pattern which is why I am confused, that and lack of knowledge in javascript

Comment: Comparisons with floating point numbers are often dicey just because of the limited precision. If your loop is either a whole number or `.5`, you could just multiple by 2 and truncate to an int and avoid floating point numbers altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic does exactly what you told it to do!

When selecting "1 hour bookings with 30 minute intervals", and start as 9:00 and end as 17:00 your variables have the following values:

`thestart` = `09`
`theend` = `17`
`thetype` = `1.5`

therefore

`calchours` = `5.333333` or `((17-9)/1.5)`

Your loop starts at zero, continues until `calchours`and increments by `1.5`. Therefore the loop only runs 4 times, giving you entries in the dynamic select of 9:00, 10:30, 12 & 13:30.

This is entirely consistent with "maths", and I came to these conclusions through the magic of "debugging". Check the console: http://jsfiddle.net/7x82d66h/

Comment: thank you for taking a look but please bare in mind that if the bookingtype is set at 1.5 then the numbers which will make it break will not be selected for instance 17 will not be shown, 16.5 will be which will make the calchours 5, if you use the 9am to 16:30 you will see that it still goes to 13:30 even though the calchours is 5

Comment: Sorry I mis-understood your answer, I see what you mean, basically it cant run 5 times as I am incrementing it 1.5 and 15x5 does not equally 5. Thanks for pointing this stupid mistake out :)